# How to make the c ++ application work with the browser

Tags: c++

How to make the c ++ application work with the browser. I mean a program that retrieves data from a given page (let's assume that the page displays a string) and then performs some reaction on the page. For example, the page displays a random string, and the program enters the length of the string into the form.

I am a novice programmer, so I care about information and advice on where to start. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You don't want to use C++ to do all of that. Better use browser extensions to do so

Comment: There are libraries that can be used to interact with web-servers and fetch individual pages. Then there's other libraries which can transform the HTML of the pages into a format that's easier to handle from your program. Start by looking for such libraries.

Comment: One easy way to interact with browser is to use Python code, there are many modules in Python to interact with browser, including standard module [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html). But you have C++ application, for that there exists Python C API that allows executing any Python script from embedded string directly inside C++ code. If you're interested precisely in this Python + C++ solution than I can create such answer.

Comment: @Arty That would be great. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you want to build everything from scratch, I would refer you to Section 11.6 of CSAPP3e (Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective 3rd Edition). There it introduces a tiny web server built upon just system calls - not using C++ but C. With this server you can perform applications as you describe -- display a random string, and so on.

Comment: @user18448131 Actually I read your question again and figured out that you need tasks that I don't know yet how to achieve. I know for sure that Python has many more convenient libraries for achieving your task. But precisely I don't know what library does exactly what you want, because never did such things. Only what I know is how to make C++ program run a Python code inside of it. But if you don't know Python then it will be difficult for you to implement such Python script even within C++. Anyway out of all your questions I know only how to embed Python code into C++.

Comment: @Arty Still, it would be helpful

Comment: @user18448131 Just made [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71627097/941531), as you requested, please put a look. :) It only shows handy way of embedding any Python code inside C++. It doesn't show anything about browsers. So you have to know Python to write further code and you have to search browsers Python modules that are useful for your tasks.

Comment: I just don't see any need to embed Python for such a simple application. Either go all C++ (with suitable libraries) or go all Python.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Embedding Python is useful in a case if there is a Strict need to have C++ application. And OP's question was only about C++. Of course if there is a freedom to choose any of two languages for whole program then pure Python solution will be definitely preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already promised to OP in comments, posting Partial answer, which doesn't answer all questions, but only provides handy tool to wrap (call) any Python code inside C++ program.

In my code snippet I don't even do anything with browsers, but instead show only example of computing [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) using Python's standard function [math.gcd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd).

I decided to introduce this Python-in-C++ bridge only because there exist many beautiful Python modules that work with browsers or with parsing/composing HTML, hence it is much easier to write such tools in Python instead of C++.

But expert without knowledge of default Python C API, it is not that easy to implement even simple use case - compile text of Python code, pass to it any arguments from C++, receive response arguments, return arguments back to C++. Only these simple actions need usage of a dozen of different Python C API functions. That's why I decided to show how to do it, as I know.

I implemented from scratch (specifically for OP's question) handy class `PyRunner` which does all the magic, usage of this class is simple:

```cpp
PyRunner pyrun;
std::string code = R"(
    def gcd(a, b):
        import math
        return math.gcd(a, b)
    res = gcd(*arg)
    print('GCD of', arg[0], 'and', arg[1], 'is', res, flush = True)
)";
std::cout << pyrun.Run(code, "(2 * 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 7)") << std::endl;
std::cout << pyrun.Run(code, "(5 * 7 * 11, 5 * 7 * 13)") << std::endl;
```

Basically you just pass any Python code snippet to `PyRunner::Run()` method and also any argument (represented as Python object converted to string). Result of this call is also a returned Python object converted to string. You can also use JSON to pass any large argument as string and parse returned argument, as any JSON string is also a valid stringized Python object.

Of course you need a knowledge of Python to be able to write complex code snippets inside C++.

One drawback of my `PyRunner` class is that for some reason (that I didn't yet understand), you can't `import` Python module inside global scope, as you can see I did `import math` within function scope. But this is not a big deal, I think, and maybe some experts will clarify the reason.

To compile and run code you need to have [pre-installed Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/), and pass Python's include folder and library file as compiler arguments. For example in Windows [CLang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases) you do following:

`clang.exe -std=c++20 -O3 -Id:/bin/Python39/include/ d:/bin/Python39/libs/python39.lib prog.cpp`

and in Linux:

`clang -std=c++20 -O3 -I/usr/include/ -lpython3.9 prog.cpp`

To run the program either you should provide environment variables `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH` or run program from Python folder (like `d:/bin/Python39/`) or do `sys.path.append("d:/bin/Python39/")` on first lines of Python code snippet embedded in C++. Without these paths Python can't find location of its standard library.

`PyRunner` class is thread-safe, but only single-threaded always.  It means that two calls to `.Run()` inside two threads will be exclusively blocked by mutex. I use [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) instead of Python's [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) to protect from multi-threading, because it is quite alright (and faster), if you don't use Python C API in any other threads simultaneously. Also it is not allowed right now to have two instances of `PyRunner` objects as it does `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_FinalizeEx()` in constructor and destructor, which should be done globally only once. Hence `PyRunner` should be a singleton.

Below is full C++ code with implementation of `PyRunner` class and its usage (usage is inside `main()`). See console output after code below. Click `Try it online!` link to see compile/run of this code on free GodBolt online Linux servers.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/Gdvc3x54b)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

#include <Python.h>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg: '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define PY_ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond) || PyErr_Occurred()) { PyErr_Print(); ASSERT_MSG(false && #cond, msg); } }
#define PY_ASSERT(cond) PY_ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define LN { std::cout << "LN " << __LINE__ << std::endl << std::flush; }

class PyRunner {
private:
    class PyObj {
    public:
        PyObj(PyObject * pobj, bool inc_ref = false) : p_(pobj) {
            if (inc_ref)
                Py_XINCREF(p_);
            PY_ASSERT_MSG(p_, "NULL PyObject* passed!");
        }
        PyObject * Get() { return p_; }
        ~PyObj() {
            Py_XDECREF(p_);
            p_ = nullptr;
        }
    private:
        PyObject * p_ = nullptr;
    };
public:
    PyRunner() {
        Py_SetProgramName(L"prog.py");
        Py_Initialize();
    }
    ~PyRunner() {
        codes_.clear();
        Py_FinalizeEx();
    }
    std::string Run(std::string code, std::string const & arg = "None") {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        code = StrUnIndent(code);
        if (!codes_.count(code))
            codes_.insert(std::pair{code, std::make_shared<PyObj>(Py_CompileString(code.c_str(), "script.py", Py_file_input))});
        PyObj & compiled = *codes_.at(code);
        PyObj globals_arg_mod = PyModule_New("arg"), globals_arg = PyModule_GetDict(globals_arg_mod.Get()), locals_arg = PyDict_New(),
              globals_mod = PyModule_New("__main__"), globals = PyModule_GetDict(globals_mod.Get()), locals = PyDict_New();
        // py_arg = PyUnicode_FromString(arg.c_str()), 
        PyObj py_arg = PyRun_String(arg.c_str(), Py_eval_input, globals_arg.Get(), locals_arg.Get());
        PY_ASSERT(PyDict_SetItemString(locals.Get(), "arg", py_arg.Get()) == 0);
        #if 0
            PyObj result = PyEval_EvalCode(compiled.Get(), globals.Get(), locals.Get());
        #else
            PyObj builtins(PyEval_GetBuiltins(), true), exec(PyDict_GetItemString(builtins.Get(), "exec"), true);
            PyObj exec_args = PyTuple_Pack(3, compiled.Get(), globals.Get(), locals.Get());
            PyObj result = PyObject_CallObject(exec.Get(), exec_args.Get());
        #endif
        PyObj res(PyDict_GetItemString(locals.Get(), "res"), true), res_str = PyObject_Str(res.Get());
        char const * cres = nullptr;
        PY_ASSERT(cres = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(res_str.Get()));
        return cres;
    }
private:
    static std::string StrUnIndent(std::string_view const & s) {
        auto lines = StrSplit(s, "\n");
        size_t min_off = size_t(-1);
        for (auto const & line: lines) {
            if (StrTrim(line).empty())
                continue;
            min_off = std::min<size_t>(min_off, line.find_first_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r "));
        }
        ASSERT(min_off < 10000ULL);
        std::string res;
        for (auto const & line: lines)
            res += line.substr(std::min<size_t>(min_off, line.size())) + "\n";
        return res;
    }
    static std::string StrTrim(std::string s) {
        s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ")); // left trim
        s.erase(s.find_last_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ") + 1); // right trim
        return s;
    }
    static std::vector<std::string> StrSplit(std::string_view const & s, std::string_view const & delim) {
        std::vector<std::string> res;
        size_t start = 0;
        while (true) {
            size_t pos = s.find(delim, start);
            if (pos == std::string::npos)
                pos = s.size();
            res.emplace_back(s.substr(start, pos - start));
            if (pos >= s.size())
                break;
            start = pos + delim.size();
        }
        return res;
    }
    
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<PyObj>> codes_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        PyRunner pyrun;
        std::string code = R"(
            def gcd(a, b):
                import math
                return math.gcd(a, b)
            res = gcd(*arg)
            print('GCD of', arg[0], 'and', arg[1], 'is', res, flush = True)
        )";
        std::cout << pyrun.Run(code, "(2 * 3 * 5, 2 * 3 * 7)") << std::endl;
        std::cout << pyrun.Run(code, "(5 * 7 * 11, 5 * 7 * 13)") << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
GCD of 30 and 42 is 6
6
GCD of 385 and 455 is 35
35
```